# Evaluating a command and assigning it to variable

Tags: csh, tcsh

How do I evaluate an example command and assign it to a variable without printing the results out using tcsh

```
 #!/bin/tcsh   
 set path=/home/uu/Desktop/ 
 egrep inn $path/filename.txt | grep en | awk '{print $3}'
```

Basically, I want to assign this line of code after executing it to a variable so that I can print it out later

```
egrep inn $path/filename.txt | grep en | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: So you want to put output of `egrep` into a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tcsh, you can assign the output of a command into a variable by enclosing the command into backticks such as:

```
set result=`egrep inn $path/filename.txt | grep en | awk '{print $3}'`
```